# How to prevent input fields from gaining keyboard focus?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I'm having problems implementing a modal dialog in HTML5: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/733

I want to programmatically disable focus on all background input fields while the modal dialog is visible. **Is there a way to programmatically prevent HTML input fields from gaining keyboard focus?**

Comment: Set them to `readonly`, granted this wouldn't work for checkbox/radio etc. `disabled` would work for all, but the values wouldn't be posted if the elements are within a form

Comment: With jQuery you can use the `blur()` function:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_blur.asp

e.g.
`$('input').blur()`

Comment: Are you maintaining all input fields inside a form?

Answer (score 0):

if you are maintaining all Input fields inside a form try this on model dialog open

```
var form = document.getElementById("your_form_id");
var elements = form.elements;
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
    elements[i].readOnly = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
function startFocusJail (focusRootElement) {
   $(document).off("focusin.focusJail");
   $(document).on("focusin.focusJail", function(event) {
      if (event.target !== focusRootElement && !$.contains(focusRootElement, event.target)) {
         focusRootElement.focus();
      }
   });
}

function stopFocusJail() {
   $(document).off("focusin.focusJail");
}
```

If a `DIV` is passed as the `focusRootElement` parameter, it must have `tabindex="-1"`.